# Conditional Probability Distributions

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Rod and Fred have reached 6-6 in their tie-break. Rod wins any point with probability R. Fred wins with probability F, where F + R = 1.

(a) Let X be the number of points until the first occasion when one or other wins two
consecutive points. Find E(X).

(b) Let Y be the number of points until the tie-break is won. Find E(Y).

(c) Let L be the event that Rod wins the tie break. Find E(X|L) and E(Y|L).

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I guess you are speaking about tennis?  Not sure everyone is familiar with the tie-break rules.  When you edit to include your efforts, I suggest explaining them.